# How to keep original value of a source property in Automapper mapping?

Tags: c#, automapper

The input view model:

```
public class FacilityInputModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The domain model:

```
public class FacilityInputModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OriginalName { get; set; }
}
```

I am to allow users to change the name of a facility but still keep its original name.

Say facility is (I am writing json just for convenience)

```
{id:1, name='Facility1', originalName='Facility1'}
```

when created.

I am to change the name by posting a `FacilityInputModel`.

```
{id:1, name='Facility2'}
```

In C# code to update the entity:

```
var entity = _repository.Find(id);
_repository.Detach(entity);
entity = Mapper.Map<Facility>(model);

_repository.Update(entity);
_repository.Save();
```

The `entity` I get before `Mapper.Map`

```
{id:1, name='Facility1', originalName='Facility1'}
```

But after the mapping, the entity is

```
{id:1, name='Facility2', originalName=null}
```

instead of

```
{id:1, name='Facility2', originalName='Facility1'}
```

In my mapping, I tried to `Ignore` the `OriginalName`

```
CreateMap<Facility, FacilityInputModel>()
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(x => x.OriginalName, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

But it never worked. Also tried

```
    .ForMember(x => x.NameInWebAdmin, opt => opt.DoNotUseDestinationValue());
```

Still won't work.

So the question is how to avoid existing values from being wiped away in the mapping. And get an after-mapping entity:

```
{id:1, name='Facility2', originalName='Facility1'}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're getting a completely new object when you call `entity = Mapper.Map<Facility>(model);`. Try using `Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, destination)` to map to an existing one.

Comment: Yes! some addition: no need for the full `Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(source, dest)`. `AutoMapper` is smart enough to handle `Mapper.Map(source, dest)`.

Comment: Actually that is c#, smart enought to figure out generic types from parameters ;)

Comment: This is so cool. I want to map properties from different classes into a view model. Just cascade them - passing in the viewmodel object as the dest each time.